# Alert and block if any url is in a form

Tags: html, forms

Would it be possible to alert and block submission of a simple form if it has a url in it? Or, to be more specific. I need it to block any of these input types:

> https //domain.com/...

or

> www domain.com//

or

> domain.com

The form must accept anything else except anything like an url.

Comment: Sure it's possible, you'd just have to write a function that validates the input and rejects it if it matches something on that list. It's not something php would do out of the box, if that's your question.

Comment: Did you tried coding anything?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$your_field_name_here)){
        //put block message or redirect here
}
```

You can try to use regex to check the existence of an URL and perform your block/redirect action.

Answer (score 0):

I would not block `domain.com` because it will consider text like `ASP.NET` to be a URL which is false. Anyways, there are a few ways to do this.

You can use [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

```
function hasUrlLink($text) {
    $check = strpos($text, 'http:') !== false || strpos($text, 'https:') !== false || strpos($text, 'www.') !== false;

    if($check) {
        return true; // Link exists
    } else {
        return false; // Link does not exist
    }
}

$text = $_POST['text'];

if(hasUrlLink($text) === true) {
    echo 'Your text has a link in it.';
}
```

---

You can also use [`strstr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) (you can also make this into a function if you want):

```
$text = $_POST['text'];

if(strstr($text, 'http:') || strstr($text, 'https:') || strstr($text, 'www.')) {
    echo 'String contains a URL';
}
```

---

Or you can also use [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) (regex). Code credit goes to [Seazoux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19463951/4357238). I just cleaned the code up a bit.:

```
function checkTextIfUrlExists($text) {
    $regex = "((https?|ftp)\:\/\/)?"; // SCHEME 
    $regex .= "([a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+(\:[a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+)?@)?"; // User and Pass 
    $regex .= "([a-z0-9-.]*)\.([a-z]{2,3})"; // Host or IP 
    $regex .= "(\:[0-9]{2,5})?"; // Port 
    $regex .= "(\/([a-z0-9+\$_-]\.?)+)*\/?"; // Path 
    $regex .= "(\?[a-z+&\$_.-][a-z0-9;:@&%=+\/\$_.-]*)?"; // GET Query 
    $regex .= "(#[a-z_.-][a-z0-9+\$_.-]*)?"; // Anchor

    if(preg_match("/^$regex$/", $text)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

$text = $_POST['text'];

if(checkTextIfUrlExists($text)) {
    echo 'URL exists!';
} else {
    echo 'URL does not exist.';
}
```